# Irreducible curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I   know  that  if  we  have  an  irreducible  curve  then a  regular  function  is  polynomial.What  it  is  the  conclusion  when  the  curve  is the  union  of  two  irreducible  components?

Comment: what does it mean for a regular function to "be polynomial"?

Comment: Jesko asked exactly the right question. This is just an exercise in the definitions, but let me just say that the property of being a "regular function" is local. Ie, a function is regular if its restrictions to open subsets is regular. From this it should be pretty straightforward to answer your own question.

Comment: @rtz Each irreducible component is a closed set. I don't know how can I ''glue'' the both polynomials to obtain a new one.

Comment: @rafa Here's an easy example for you to ponder. The ring of regular functions on the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes in the affine plane over $k$ is $k[x,y]/(xy)$